# How to write common "if" branching in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following snippet of code:

```
srcaddr <- getIfaceAddr iface >>= inet_ntoa . fromJust 
dstaddr <- getDestAddr iface >>= inet_ntoa . fromJust 
-- I want to perform actions only if neither getIfaceAddr 
-- nor getDestAddr returned Nothing
action1 srcaddr dstaddr
action2 srcaddr dstaddr
action3 srcaddr dstaddr

getIfaceAddr :: String -> IO (Maybe HostAddress)
getDestAddr :: String -> IO (Maybe HostAddress)
```

How to write this code in 'nice Haskell'? I was thinking about the MaybeT monad but somehow wasn't able make it work. I was trying to do some 'lifting', but wasn't able to stich the types together. I can change the signature of the getIfaceAddr/getDestAddr.

As a sidenote: why is inet_ntoa 'HostAddress -> IO String'? I don't think there are any side effects, are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh my, what is that `fromJust`?  If `getIfaceAddr` returns `Nothing`, this code will crash your program.

The `MaybeT` solution looks like this:

```
srcaddr <- lift . inet_ntoa =<< MaybeT (getIfaceAddr iface)
dstaddr <- lift . inet_ntoa =<< MaybeT (getDestAddr iface)
lift $ do
    action1 srcaddr dstaddr
    ...
```

The types for the first line fit together like this:

```
getIfaceAddr iface          :: IO (Maybe HostAddress)
MaybeT (getIfaceAddr iface) :: MaybeT IO HostAddress
inet_ntoa                   :: HostAddress -> IO String
lift . inet_ntoa            :: HostAddress -> MaybeT IO String
lift . inet_ntoa =<< MaybeT (getIfaceAddr iface)
                            :: MaybeT IO String
```

Remember that your code is going to have type `MaybeT IO something`, so you have to `runMaybeT` to get it back into `IO` before binding it to `main`.

Comment: Yep, that's why I am asking - because I didn't like the fromJust :)

Answer (score 6):

Another, helperless solution:

```
msrcaddr <- getIfaceAddr iface >>= traverse inet_ntoa
mdstaddr <- getDestAddr iface >>= traverse inet_ntoa
case liftM2 (,) msrcaddr mdstaddr of
   Just (srcaddr,dstaddr) ->
      action1 srcaddr dstaddr
      action2 srcaddr dstaddr
      action3 srcaddr dstaddr
   Nothing -> return ()
```

You can also replace the case with a `maybe`, if you prefer. Or you can avoid the liftM2 by just pattern matching out of the pair directly.

Edit: Here's a link to the documentation for Traversable, an overlooked but frequently indispensable typeclass: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Traversable.html

Answer (score 1):

A helper function can do this with pattern matching?

```
help x y
     where
     help (Just a) (Just b) = -- actions here ?
     help _        _        = return ()
```

Comment: Yep - I could pass the result of getIfaceAddr to the helper function and do the inet_ntoa there. I am just getting a little tired of 'Create a helper function' answer on everything.

Comment: Fortunately you can use `liftM2` function for `Maybe` monad from `Control.Monad` instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as an "if-branching" like this:

```
import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

...
  mSrcaddr <- fmap inet_ntoa $ getIfaceAddr iface
  mDstaddr <- fmap inet_ntoa $ getDestAddr iface
  when (isJust mSrcaddr && isJust mDstaddr) $ do
    let Just srcaddr = mSrcaddr
        Just dstaddr = mDstaddr
    action1 srcaddr dstaddr
    action2 srcaddr dstaddr
    action3 srcaddr dstaddr
```

But I don't like being in the bad habit of writing the kinds of pattern matches that could potentially fail and crash my program, even though in this case it is safe.

Also, I don't like using `isJust` and friends and manually testing; the `Maybe` type already means "something that could fail", and there are built-in functions which allow us to preserve that meaning while using `Maybe` values.

So I would probably write it like this:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

...
  mSrcaddr <- fmap inet_ntoa $ getIfaceAddr iface
  mDstaddr <- fmap inet_ntoa $ getDestAddr iface
  fromMaybe (return ()) $ liftA2 doActions mSrcaddr mDstaddr
where
  doActions srcaddr dstaddr = do
      action1 srcaddr dstaddr
      action2 srcaddr dstaddr
      action3 srcaddr dstaddr
```

Yeah, I know, a helper function. Sorry, that's how I'd actually write it in real life. :)